# Tool to check up ssl setup on apache server

Tags: ssl, apache

My Apache server works fine  without -DSSL, but does not start with SSL.  This happened after I re-install the certificate because of expiration. (it used to work before)  I would love to have some tool to check up if my newer setup of ssl key and certificate is correct or not. That would include permission, ownership etc..
Or is there any way to figure out why it doesn't work with SSL?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can check your configuration files for syntax errors without starting the server by using `apachectl configtest` or the `-t` command line option.

That said, I don't think that Apache fails silently. There must be something in Apache's logs. Can you check this and provide the trace?

PS: You should add details on your environment such as your OS (Windows, GNU/Linux, Unix, etc), the Apache version, etc. This could help.

Comment: This doesn't test whether the SSL certificates are set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed `apachectl configtest` doesn't check whether the certificate actually matches the key. If they don't match, the logging of apache (even 14 years after this question got asked) isn't very clear about it.

I use the following commands before deploying a new keypair to check if they match. I include the initial certificate signing request, so if they don't match, I can quickly see where it went wrong.

```
openssl req -noout -modulus -in [the original signing request] | openssl md5
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in [the signed certificate] | openssl md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in [the key] | openssl md5
```

The results of these commands should be identical.

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest, https://globalsign.ssllabs.com/ if your website is publically available.